# Node POST request - receive data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a POST request to my node/express server, to send an email. I would like to pass through the details of the email via the request, but am not able to get the data on the node side.

This is what I've got so far *note: the email send part is psuendo code*

**index.js**

```
var jsonDataObj = {'to': 'example@exmpale', 'subject': 'this is the subject','text': 'this is the text',};
const response = await fetch('/api/hello', {
  method: 'post',
  body: jsonDataObj
});
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/api/hello', (req, res) => {

  const msg = {
    to: req.body.to,
    subject: req.body.subject,
    text: req.body.text
  };

  sendEmail(msg);
});

app.listen();
```

Comment: "but am not able to get the data on the node side" -> Your server doesnt start on my side, you have 2 express inclusions and have not defined bodyParser, fix your question by providing a working minimum example :)

Comment: Yeah really the answer is just to fix up the basic issues above and you're also missing `app.listen(....` at the end. You can also do `process.exit(1)` after the `console.log` which halts code execution at which point I get the posted data as you expected.

Comment: Apologies - I extracted a snippet from the file, to try to provide a quick overview. I've fixed issues with my sample code.

Comment: When you say you're not able to "get data on the node side", what do you mean? Using your new provided code I was able to log and verify that the body content is being sent to the server. Are you sure you're using the right encoding format?

Comment: Code sample is working, posting data with Postman results in what you'd expect, ensure that the `jsonDataObj` that you're posting there is what it is expected to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> var jsonDataObj = {'to': 'example@exmpale', 'subject': 'this is the subject','text': 'this is the text',};
> ```

[That is a JavaScript object, not JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

When you pass it to `fetch`, it will be converted to a string by calling its `toString()` method.

```js
var jsonDataObj = {'to': 'example@exmpale', 'subject': 'this is the subject','text': 'this is the text',};
console.log(jsonDataObj.toString());
```

This:

- is not JSON
- is not url encoded
- doesn't actually contain any of your data

You need to encode the data in a format that can be sent over HTTP.

For example, this will sent in multipart format:

```
var jsonDataObj = {'to': 'example@exmpale', 'subject': 'this is the subject','text': 'this is the text',};
var data = new FormData();
Object.keys(jsonDataObj).forEach(key => data.append(key, jsonDataObj[key]));
const response = fetch('/api/hello', {
  method: 'post',
  body: data
});
```

… which you can read with [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme).

While this will encode using a query string which `bodyParser.urlencoded` should be able to handle.

```
var jsonDataObj = {'to': 'example@exmpale', 'subject': 'this is the subject','text': 'this is the text',};
var data = new URLSearchParams();
Object.keys(jsonDataObj).forEach(key => data.append(key, jsonDataObj[key]));
const response = fetch('/api/hello', {
  method: 'post',
  body: data,
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
});
```

And this will actually use JSON:

```
var jsonDataObj = {'to': 'example@exmpale', 'subject': 'this is the subject','text': 'this is the text',};
var data = JSON.stringify(jsonDataObj);
const response = fetch('/api/hello', {
  method: 'post',
  body: data,
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
});
```

Comment: Nice explanation, suspected that this was the issue but too lazy to make an answer :0

Comment: Thank you - appreciate the effort of the answer, makes a lot more sense now.